# Dispose a SemaphoreSlim while WaitAsync

Tags: .net, multithreading, semaphore, dispose, idisposable

The documentation of SemaphoreSlim says 'Dispose should only be used when all other operations have completed'.

How should the following class be adjusted so thread B can call Dispose() while thread A is awaiting Async(). Async() must throw an ObjectDisposedException when Dispose() is called.

```
class A
{
   SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
   public Task Async() { return _sem.WaitAsync(); }
   public void Dispose() { _sem.Dispose(); }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want thread B to call `Dispose()` in this case?

Comment: Dispose is called as a means of cancelling all pending requests and releasing resources.

Comment: But there's no reason why `Dispose()` should cancel anything. If you want to cancel, then cancel on a `CancellationToken` passed to `WaitAsync` and any other asynchronous methods in the same batch of requests.

Answer (score 0):

> How should the following class be adjusted so thread B can call Dispose() while thread A is awaiting Async()

It shouldn't. As the documentation you quote says, if all operations aren't completed, then `Dispose()` shouldn't be called. If there's a thread still awaiting `WaitAsync()` then that operation isn't completed, and therefore `Dispose()` should not be called.

From a comment:

> Dispose is called as a means of cancelling all pending requests and releasing resources.

That's an ill-advised way of cancelling a request.

Sure, if you do something that puts an object into an invalid state it **could** cause exceptions in other threads that **could** result in them aborting and hence abandoning their work.

But there's no guarantee that they should do so, and there's also a good chance that they would be coded so as to not expect such an exception at such a point and clean up appropriately.

If you want to cancel, do a normal cancellation. Create the task thus:

```
public Task Async(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  return _sem.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

And use `cancellationToken` to cancel.

Comment: Jon Hanna, HttpClient.Dispose is an example of a method which cancels pending requests and releases resources. Internally it uses a cancellationToken.Can you give a code example which Disposes the semaphore and uses a cancellationToken while keeping the interface of class A?

Comment: "HttpClient.Dispose is an example of a method which cancels pending requests and releases resources" Not quite; it releases resources, and doing that means cancelling pending requests, because it is a HTTP client. "Can you give a code example which Disposes the semaphore and uses a cancellationToken while keeping the interface of class A" No, the interface is not defined as allowing for cancellation. If it neither accepts a token in the method call, nor has a way to set a token for all methods called, then it's not defined as supporting cancellation...

Comment: ... If however you can add to the interface but not remove, then you could add a property or constructor parameter to set a token to be used by all methods of the class, perhaps defaulting to `CancellationToken.None`.

Comment: But the CancellationToken doesn't solve the issue too. Even if you call {_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); _sem.Dispose(); } still leaves some _sem.WaitAsync(cancellationToken) in a black hole till the process exists! What is the best way to dispose class A?